# Query string in AWS Application Load Balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer, amazon-elb

I want to route everything going to service.php to be routed to a specific target group, even if it has a query string or not. Do I need to define it with a wildcard or is just defining /service.php sufficient enough?

`/service.php` vs `/service.php*`

In addition to this, I also want to route a specific query with its parameters to another target group, how would I define this? Could I just do `/service.php?mobile=true*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#path-conditions

the paths are regular expressions that need to exactly match so you would need to define a rule like /service.php*

To handle sending mobile requests to a different target group you might create two rules with different priority.  Elastic Load Balancing evaluates rules in priority order, from the lowest value to the highest value. If a request satisfies a rule, Elastic Load Balancing ignores all subsequent rules, so you would want your mobile rule to have a lower priority than your service rule.

/service.php?mobile?true*

/service.php*

Note the allowed characters in the documentation.

Comment: I appreciate it! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you.

Comment: Hi,
I tried adding two rules :
    `/api/*_mobile*`
    `/api/*`

It works correctly for `/api/abc/_mobile` but does not work as expected for `/api/xyz/?_mobile=true`. Is there anything wrong with the config?